# Adjust height of div/section by content

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, height

I have a section which is filled by javascript. Basically it creates an iframe inside with another html content where i have no control over. i could set the height manually but its a responsive site and the height will change.

Setting the height of the section to `height: fit-content;` doesnt work because the next element is the iframe which has no height itself. When i set the height of the iframe in the inspector it works so `fit-content` works but i have no height.

is there a way to get the current display height? I also could search for a child class with the correct height or is there a better way?

```css
#SectionID{
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<section id="SectionID">

<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//jsfiddle.net/dichterD/ny0k6d27/embedded/result/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<!-- iframe is 100% height, content of iframe is html > body > div (with height defined) -->
<!-- no control over iframe content -->

</section>
```

i could embed the iframe directly to give it an id. what i would like to achieve is the iframe always in the correct height - also responsive.
so i would have to get something like the scrollheight or offsetheight.

```
Height = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].scrollHeight;
```

gives me 150px (which is the iframe height), `html` gives me 8px. the div inside the iframe section is 550px.

maybe im calling the js at the wrong time

Comment: would you share codepen example link please? i dont understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically set the height of the  based on the content inside the `<iframe`, you can use JavaScript. However, you need to make sure that you are accessing the content inside the `iframe` after it has loaded. You can achieve this by attaching an `onload` event listener to the `iframe`.

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
        #SectionID {
          height: fit-content;
        }
      </style>
      <script>
        function adjustSectionHeight() {
          var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    
          if (iframe) {
            iframe.onload = function() {
              var contentHeight = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
              document.getElementById('SectionID').style.height = contentHeight + 'px';
            };
          }
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <section id="SectionID">
        <iframe id="myIframe" width="100%" height="100%" src="//jsfiddle.net/dichterD/ny0k6d27/embedded/result/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </section>
    
      <script>
        // Call the function after the page has loaded
        window.onload = function() {
          adjustSectionHeight();
        };
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This will of course only work if the iframe content is loaded from the same origin; otherwise the Same Origin Policy will prevent you from accessing its content, to measure the height.

Comment: that will be the case. the interresting thing is, that i can see the iframe document in my dom opening the inspector with all the size data i need. is there a way to find an element in the dom inside the iframe when i know the ID?

Comment: I get the iframe in the correct size when i set the iframe to position:absolute but then i have different problems positioning the iframe correctly.